# Answer that should not have been deleted

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

I just ran into [this answer](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/a/11560/6299) that was deleted.  Maybe there is some legalistic hair-splitting reason why it was deleted.  But my lord, it's **the right answer**.   He asked her out on a date (see [Seinfeld](http://seinfeld.wikia.com/wiki/The_Phone_Message)).  She said **no**.  Not maybe, not I'm busy, not "it's too far", just plain no.  What more needs to be said?  You could maybe disagree with this answer, but delete it???

Answer (score 5):

From the comment of the answer:

> please see [here](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2511/what-is-the-difference-between-not-answering-a-question-and-posting-a-frame-chal) what we require of frame challenges like this. This post misses a justification of why the frame of the question is a bad idea. Why shouldn't the OP tell the girl? What would be the consequences of doing so?

So, if you think this answer is "*the right answer*", you should definitely make the same with the justifications that this answer miss (unless another, not deleted, answer already do that).

Answers on this site that does not "back it up" tend to be deleted which explain why this one has been.

Comment: The answer is an **extremely useful** answer.  The fact that it was deleted indicates a problem with site policy.

Comment: @DaveG I think Noon's point is that it wasn't removed for being not-useful, it was removed for not meeting the standards of answers on this site. Keeping some standards is important, and I think you'd need to make a more detailed argument if you want to argue in favor of relaxing those standards that refutes the arguments made in the linked meta post.

Comment: @BryanKrause in the case I'd say "back it up" doesn't even apply, since the answer merely points what the OP is saying: he asked her out for coffee, she said "no way".  I'm not sure what there would be to "back up"... no means no?

Comment: @DaveG Are we looking at the same question? I see OP saying the response was "I'm too lazy to leave home"

Comment: @BryanKrause Yep, that's what I'm referring to.  "I'm too lazy ..." which sure sounds like "no, no way".  Not "what time" or "how about lunch" or "I have to wash my hair", just plain no.  There's not a lot of wiggle room in the answer.

Comment: @DaveG I think at a minimum an answer that is going to say "I'm too lazy" means "no" (which I don't entirely agree with, by the way) needs an explanation of why someone might use that as a way of saying "no" - I completely agree that an answer that says only what you have said in comments here should be deleted because it lacks the justification that we require from frame challenges, as in the linked meta.

Comment: (and note that [this answer](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/a/11483/3089) already does this to some extent, at least by raising the possibility that there are multiple ways to interpret that statement, including a gentle "no, never")

Comment: @BryanKrause I'd answer you but I'm too lazy.

Comment: Should I take that to mean you won't answer me *just this time* or you won't answer me *in response to anything else ever*? Without other information, and given the context, the former seems reasonable to expect. Hence why I think "I'm too lazy" may or may not mean "no, never, but I want to let you down easy" like in the answer I linked.