# Was this answer an improper frame challenge?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-answer

I'm pretty new here, so I am trying to get a better feel for the scope, etiquette, and topicality of this site.

I recently answered a question [here](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/a/20767/14379), which was moderately well received.

However, after reading a little more about how to navigate this site I stumbled upon the inherent problem with [frame challenges](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2511/what-is-the-difference-between-not-answering-a-question-and-posting-a-frame-chal), and to be honest I'm not really sure why my answer wasn't considered one.

Wasn't my first section a frame challenge? If it was why wasn't it received more negatively? Was there something about the way I approached the answer that made it acceptable? If it is a problem is there a way for me to rephrase my answer to be less problematic?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Wasn't my first section a frame challenge? If it was why wasn't it received more negatively? Was there something about the way I approached the answer that made it acceptable?

Indeed your answer is a frame challenge, but it fulfills what we expect from a frame-challenge answer.

The meta post you linked mentions following points a frame-challenge answer must have.

> Here is what I see necessary for a good frame challenge on IPS:
>
> - A clear explanation of why the author disagrees with the frame of the question.
> - A presentation of an alternate frame
> - An explanation of how the new frame will solve the OP's problem

So, first paragraph of your answer explains why you disagree with current frame of the question. The second paragraph mentions an alternate approach followed by explanation why it would work.

This is why you got a good response from the community.

The frame challenge answers you may have stumbled upon was perhaps poorly received because they didn't fulfill the criteria.

> If it is a problem is there a way for me to rephrase my answer to be less problematic?

I don't see at the moment though, but if there is any, you might be notified in comments by the community.