# What to do when a new version of a closed question indirectly invalidate existing answers?

Tags: discussion, answers, closed-questions, editing, asking-questions

[This question](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/20433/86) is downvoted and closed for being unclear, and has one answer. I now have a better version of this, which removes all unnecessary information and states what I think clearer. What should I do?

- Edit the old one, because I need to fix bad questions?
- Ask a new one, because it may "invalidate" the current answer?

I don't think that answer is invalidated, but it is written in a pessimistic view. The new version presents 4 more options to solve the problem and explains why they would work, thus indirectly invalidate it. One option even elaborates how I would follow the solution given in the answer, further makes it unnecessary. Still, it is an on-topic answer.

Another convenience of editing is that I can add this line:

> Here I only describe what is relevant to solve the problem. For a full background, you can read the past version of this question.

What do you think?

<sup>Related: [The objective aspect of subjective questions](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3458/86)</sup>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The new version presents 4 more options to solve the problem and explains why they would work

That does not sound as if you're making your question clearer. It sounds like you found four possible ways to solve your problem and want us to pick one for you.

> One option even elaborates how I would follow the solution given in the answer, further makes it unnecessary

Editing your question in a way that includes, yet invalidates a given answer isn't going to make that answerer happy. In general, edits should not be used as rebuttals to answers.

In general, people aren't going to be happy if you change your question enough that it invalidates their answer. On the other hand, answering an unclear or too broad question comes with the risk that an edit will be made that invalidates your answer. If you do edit, make sure to let the original answerer know you've made such an edit, and kindly ask them to take appropriate action on their answer too.

> Another convenience of editing is that I can add this line:
>
> Here I only describe what is relevant to solve the problem. For a full background, you can read the past version of this question.

This is a big ***NO***. Your question should stand on its own, not be dependent on edit history. If the background is needed to properly answer the question it should be in the question, if it isn't, don't distract people with it or try to have them answer previous revisions.

---

Given all this, I suggest you run your 'improved' question through our [Sandbox](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3129/sandbox-for-proposed-questions?cb=1) first, here you can get feedback on shaping the question itself and we can properly see and judge whether this should be a new question or an edit, as it's very hard to gather from your question here what you're planning to do, whether it would be an actual improvement to the question or make an entirely different question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, here is the [sandbox](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3468/86). To answer your questions, no, I just want you to help me see the holes in my logic. I have noted to that answerer that I'm about to edit. I also think that I don't hide any necessary information in the past revision, and don't see why that note is distracting.

Comment: **I don't see where in this post I'm asking you questions... There isn't a single question mark in the entire answer**. If you want to make a proper IPS post, discussing something concrete (like the sandbox post, I'll look at that later today or else after New Year's) is much better than vague question about objective aspects or editing vs. new question. And yes, putting up a note about past revisions *is* distracting, even if you don't see it.